# Round ring button in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

I want to create a button background (or button itself) that look exactly like the below one.

[image]

I'm doing it currently with an image. I tried to create a similar one using the following XML, but it doesn't look as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
   <solid
     android:color="#f0600000"/>
   <stroke
     android:width="10dp"
     android:color="#FFFF6666"/>
</shape>
```

Actually I want a round button with 3 pixel shadow and 1/4 width stroke in red color around the white circle. I have not succeeded with the shadow part at all. Thanks for any sort of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solid fills the middle and stroke paints the border. Since you want 3 colors you will have to use 2 drawables, painting white circle over the red circle with grey border. You can then use [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) to keep these as one unit

Comment: The only think I can think is to paint yet another drawable - transparent grey as the first drawable and slightly move it off center in direction of the shadow

Comment: Actually - based on your drawing you can paint 1-st fuzzy grey oval and then paint white oval with red border over it

Comment: @RonyJoy if you come up with implementation can you please post it? It really helps